# How to check if server control text contains html entity(Checkmark, cross etc.)?

Tags: asp.net, html-entities, linkbutton

Weird but it is becoming problem for me!
I have added an html checkmark with this code ✔ to my linkbutton text but when I am trying to check this

```
if(headerLinkButton.Text == "&#x2714;")
```

it returns me false!
and when I check its text putting breakpoint, it shows the same checkmark that it shows on browser!
[image]

Strange How can I simulate a checkmark in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
switch(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(headerLinkButton.Text)) 
{
    case "&#x2714;":
       // do your stuff
}
```

Or Alternately

```
if(headerLinkButton.Text == HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#x2714;"))
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: Great! Man, Thanks! Although your first solution is not working, but the second one(if(headerLinkButton.Text == HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#x2714;"))) did the job :)